# Controllable table fields in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a website where there are table (10x10) with adverts inside (pictures+links). I created this table and created one advert, which leads to testlink.com and has picture "img100x100.png". How could i change the code, so I can get different links and images for each table data cell? Please explain as much as possible, because I have just started to learn PHP & MySQL.

I currently have the following code in index.php:

```
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <body>


    <?php

    $rows_max    = 10;
    $columns_max = 10;

    $links = Array(
    'link' => "http://testlink.com",
    'image' => "img100x100.png");

    print '<table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
    for($row = 1; $row <= $rows_max; $row++) 
        {
        print '<tr>';
        for($col = 1; $col <= $columns_max; $col++)
            {
                print '<td width="10px" height="10px" background="'.$links["image"].'" >';
                print '<a href="'.$links["link"].'"><center> </center></a>';
                print '</td>';
            }
        print '</tr>';
        }

    print '</table>';

    include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

and

```
td a
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could link this up to a database with 10 rows and foreach through those. Or even simpler, you could have this all in an array. It would be a lot easier if you didn't use a table and just made them square with CSS and floated them left in a container. You would get a similar result.

```
$links = array(
    array(
        'url' => 'http://link.com/',
        'image' => 'image.jpg'
    ),        array(
        'url' => 'http://link.com/',
        'image' => 'image.jpg'
    ),        array(
        'url' => 'http://link.com/',
        'image' => 'image.jpg'
    )
    // etc
);
```

Then

```
foreach($links as $link){
    // Code to build out a cell
    echo $link['url'];
    echo $link['image'];
}
```

Comment: When is the usage of MYSQL necessary? I saved $links array, but without using MYSQL. Why should I use MYSQL, when php already saved the values in array for me?

Comment: Well.. if you ever want to add or remove a link, you need to edit your PHP code that way. If you use a database, you have the potential to allow others to add and remove links or doing so easier, without PHP knowledge by building an interface that adds links/manages links in the database.

Comment: I get your code. But in my case, i should repeat that array 100 times, right? Is there any easier way to create these arrays?

Comment: I guess I don't understand: are these 100 unique links/images? Or do you just want to specify a few and have it randomly select them? If you want 100 unique link/image pairs, then you have to specify them somewhere, whether its a database or an array, right? How else would your code know what to display?

Comment: They are indeed unique, and permanent after i assign them. But I want an opportunity to the advertisers to display their add bigger than in one table cell, if they want (for example 2 cells together, 3 cells together, etc)